# Can I prevent users from loading images in emails (disable “re-enable the blocked features”)

Tags: email, exchange, microsoft-office-365

Using only Office 365 with no onsite AD or exchange infrastructure.

1. Can I push out a policy or something to online and local installations of outlook to control whether images are automatically displayed in emails for users with exchange-online? It seems to already prevent the display of images by default, but is that a configurable policy?
2. Can I prevent users from loading images in emails completely? Meaning it is set to not load images automatically and users will not even be able to click "re-enable the blocked features" to view the images.
3. Can I prevent "re-enable the blocked features" per domain? I still want users to be able to receive messages from a URL, I just want to prevent them from loading images in emails from that URL

I was hoping there was a way exchange online could do something like strip out the URLs of image links before they get to a recipient's mailbox so regardless of what mail client the user is viewing the email with they will not be able to download images.

Answer (score 0):

With Group Policy you can force client configuration to not download an entire message, and to open messages by default as plain text. But users can always override these, so after opening a message they can switch to HTML view.

I'm not sure of any way to "block" specific links or change their behavior from inside Exchange. Transport rules will let you detect the links and you can block the entire message and provide an explanation, but you can't modify the message itself.

If it's malicious threats or redirects you are worried about then you may want to consider Advanced Threat Protection which does real time link checking.

If all access is behind a firewall or proxy - you may potentially be able to control access there.

Comment: Ah but that's the tricky part the link refer s to a domain I don't want to block because users won't be able to send and receive emails to it